# How to shorten MaterialTheme.colors.primary?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When coding with compose we use MaterialTheme code so much. Is there a way to shorten this part of the code? for example: `mColor.primay`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best answer is this:

```
val mColors: MColor()   @Composable get() = MyTheme.colors
```

and we can call colors like this:  `mColors.primary`
We can do this for typography, shapes and dimensions as well.

Comment: I had forgotten about setters and getters with `@Composable` annotation. Good catch

Answer (score 5):

This is less of a Jetpack Compose solution - more of "using Kotlin language features".

You can use the `with` scope function to make `MaterialTheme`, which is an `object`, an implicit receiver. Then you can refer to `colors.primary` or `colors.whatever` without saying `MaterialTheme`.

You can surround the entire enclosing function with a `with` block:

```
@Composable
fun foo() {
    with(MaterialTheme) {
        // compose your view here...
        // and you can say "colors.primary" instead of 
        // "MaterialTheme.colors.primary" in here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, simply use a type alias to make the name `MaterialTheme` shorter:

```
typealias MT = MaterialTheme
// now you can say "MT.colors.primary" instead of "MaterialTheme.colors.primary"
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this can be done in various ways. One of them being

```
val mColor
    get() =  @Composable{
        MaterialTheme.colors
    }
```

usage

```
mColor().primary
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I call this without parentheses? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. This is a @Composable lambda,  so you need to invoke it to get `Colors` to get properties like `primary`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I could access to mColors without parentheses by doing this: `val mColors: MyColor  @Composable get() = MaterialTheme.colors`

Comment: Great. I forgot about. Post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with function.

```
@Composable
fun materialThemeColor() = MaterialTheme.colors
```

While using you can use

```
   color = materialThemeColor().primary
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to call this function without parentheses?